# How is bandwidth and roughness penalty in nonparametric regression connected?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, regularization, smoothing

Nonparametric regression, or smoothing, concerns finding a function that smooths the data, and appears in additive models or generalized additive models. You could say we are trying to fit the model

$$y_i=f(x_i)+e_i$$

with a loosely specified $f$.

One general approach to finding $f$ is a moving average type of approach, saying that $f(x)$ is estimated via taking a weighted average of nearby $y_i$. Often this involves picking a bandwidth parameter controlling how many nearby observations are effectively used in the average, and influences the roughness of the resulting estimated function and its prediction quality.

Another general approach is the the penalized regression approach, where we minimize the sum of squared errors of the fit plus a cost of the function that is high for wiggly functions. This comes with a roughness penalty parameter that controls how much to penalize a function for being wiggly.

These are often the most important parameters in getting good nonparametric estimates that serve similar functions. I suspect they are very closely related to each other despite the different mathematical phrasing, perhaps being tied together by a deeper mathematical theory. What would that theory be?

Comment: +1, this is a very involved question. Please see my answer below where I try to expand on this.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between spline estimators and spline estimators is far from trivial. The "best starting reference" is likely: Lin et al. (2004) [Equivalent kernels of smoothing splines in nonparametric regression for clustered/longitudinal data](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/91/1/177/218863)  but it is a very technical paper. Maybe, one finds Nychka (1995) [Splines as Local Smoothers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-23/issue-4/Splines-as-Local-Smoothers/10.1214/aos/1176324704.full) easier to follow but I personally found the exposition in Lin et al. cleaner and the examples more helfpul.

In general, I think one should first build some familiarity with the asymptotic optimality of Generalised Cross-Validation. An obvious reference on the matter is Li's (1987) [Asymptotic Optimality for $C_p$, $C_L$, Cross-Validation and Generalized Cross-Validation: Discrete Index Set](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-15/issue-3/Asymptotic-Optimality-for-C_p-C_L-Cross-Validation-and-Generalized-Cross/10.1214/aos/1176350486.full) where the connection with nearest-neighbour nonparametric regression is discussed in detailed.  Following that, Smirnoff (1996) [Smoothing Methods
in Statistics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4026-6) Sect. 5.8 "*Comparing Non-parametric Regression Methods*" has a short casual discussion and it is the only place I have seen a book commenting on how local polynomial estimators generalise to arbitrary likelihoods via the idea of a local likelihood. Finally, we get to the papers mentioned in the beginning and particularly to the sections 3 & 4 by Lin et al.